# App development in C.

Tags: iphone, c

I have a silly question. So, i'm currenly learning to program in C and I'd like to know if it is possible to create Iphone applications in C language. I searched the web and got an impression that all Iphone applications are written in Objective-C, is this really the case? 
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Objective-C is a superset of C, i.e., anything you can do in C you can do in O-C.  Leaving this as a comment though as I am not familiar with the various API's that make up iOS development and I may very well be missing some caveats.

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL some people love object-oriented; others think it is one big "OOPS!" Don't complain about someone-else's choice, just because you don't agree, (and don't complain if you do agree for that matter either).

Answer (score 3):

Anything you can do in C, you can also do in Objective-C.  However, most of Apple's Cocoa Touch libraries are only available through Objective-C calls.

Plus, not only is Objective-C on its own a fairly nice language, Cocoa Touch provides *so many* useful API calls that you wouldn't want to miss out on them.  It's really incredible when you get down into many of the methods Apple provides for you - it's staggering.  Even just the NSString* operations are impressive.

Note that you can (and sometimes must) still use plain C for many operations, thanks to [Toll-Free Bridging](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/Articles/tollFreeBridgedTypes.html).  Many of the `NS___` classes (used in Obj-C) used in CocoaTouch are directly compatible with the Core Foundation methods and types `CF___` (used in C).

Besides, if for nothing else, once you start using the Objective-C method naming system (with named arguments) you can't go back.  :)

Answer (score 2):

You can technically write an application in just C, yes, but in order to interface to the Apple-provided frameworks you'd need to write your application in Objective-C, which isn't difficult to pick up at all, and well worth your time.

Answer (score 2):

If you are just wanting to learn C, there is no real reason to write an iPhone app.  Just write some command line tools on the Mac and that'll give you a firm grasp of C.

However, if your goal is to eventually write iOS or Mac OS X applications, you need to know Objective-C anyway.  In fact, much of modern Objective-C is all about hiding the insanity of C anyway.

Since Objective-C is a superset of C, focusing on Objective-C first will give you a foundation in writing apps for iOS or the Mac while also teaching you the basics of C.  If you want to dive more deeply into C, you'll then have a foundation for doing so.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Objective-C is really just a way to organise code and data in a C program. You should learn the objective-c syntax, which once you know C will only take you a little while as there isn't much in addition. But learning C is a great start to learning how to make iOS apps.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually both C and Objective-C code will be compiled down to machine code; so it's quite certainly possible.

Unfortunately as far as I know, the official API is in Objective-C so It would likely be a **little** more difficult to interface with the APIs but if you're up to it I would say give it a shot.

Also it seems perfectly possible form what I can read here:
http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/52352-ansi-c-objective-c.html

Although they seem to be using a Objective-C to interface with the libraries.

But it's certainly not impossible.  Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

The development environment for iOS is programming in Objective-C using the Xcode IDE and Cocoa-Touch framework. It is a powerful and fast way to develop native iPhone apps. You technically can compile C code within iOS but why would you want to do that?

Objective-C might look funny coming from a C background but it's actually very easy when you get used to it (in fact I find it very natural) and the Xcode IDE gives you a lot of support with code completion etc.

Comment: I have no intentions of making any applications right this moment. I just wanted to know if I had the possibility to make some apps maybe in the near future, if I learned to program in C. Would you say I should quit learning C and maybe learn Objective-C instead or should i learn C first , and then learn C# ? Thank you.

Comment: Depends on what you want to do really. I'd say think about what you want to achieve and then ask another question here about what technology you should use to achieve that, see what answers you get.